# How can I get result of find() as model name array?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How can I get result of find() as model name array?
For now, main table is getting as field name, but other joined tables are stored in model name array.

```
class ArticleMainsTable extends Table {
 $this->belongsTo(
        'TopicMasters', [
            'className' => 'TopicMasters',
            'foreignKey' => 'topic_id'
        ]
 );

 function get() {
   return $this->find('all', ['contain' => 'TopicMasters'])->first()->toArray();
 }

}
```

It returns like following structure.

```
['id'] // From ArticleMainTable.
['title'] // From ArticleMainTable
....
['topic_master'] // There is another layer and it contains fields of
```

For fields of ArticleMainTable, I want to access same layer as TopicMasterTable.
So, ['article_main']['id'] like that.

How can get main table data same as joined tables structure?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Updating an older CakePHP application that uses that structure and you don't want to change your code? I have to advise biting the bullet and making the change. Trying to work against something so fundamental is going to cause you a lot more pain in the long run.

Comment: Converting to arrays instead of using entity objects is also throwing out a lot of great functionality, such as type safety and virtual fields, plus you have to work with entities when you're doing edits, so you may as well get used to working with them all the time.

Comment: @GregSchmidt
>Updating an older CakePHP application that uses that structure and you don't want to change your code?
Totally correct. Because my customer's system is fetching data and refilling from fetched data.
So, I wanted to keep current structure.

Comment: I've been through this update process a few times. The first time, I tried to do what you're trying to do. I very much regret the time and effort that I put into it, and wish I had just embraced entities right from the start.